# How to get AVPlayer's specific HTTP error

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I developed a Swift iOS application that plays live video transmissions. The server is not under my control.

The server session may expire after a specific period of time, so I have to log in again. When this happens, the server sends an HTTP code 302. The problem is that although I can get the error `NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects`, I can not get the original 302 that is causing this. Also, I get `NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects` after 20 seconds due to AVPlayer attempts, but the original error is immediate.

My code:

```
func play(url: URL) {
    let cookiesArray = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!
    let values = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookiesArray)
    let cookieArrayOptions = ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": values]
    let assets = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: cookieArrayOptions)
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: assets)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
    
    // Add observer for AVPlayer status and AVPlayerItem status
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.status), options: [.new, .initial], context: nil)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status), options:[.new, .initial], context: nil)
    
    // Watch notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.newErrorLogEntry(notification:)), name: .AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, object: player.currentItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.failedToPlayToEndTime(notification:)), name: .AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
    
    player.play()
}

// Observe If AVPlayerItem.status Changed to Fail
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if object is AVPlayer, let newStatusAsNumber = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? NSNumber {
        if #keyPath(AVPlayer.status) == keyPath && newStatusAsNumber.intValue == AVPlayerStatus.failed.rawValue {
            NSLog("observeValue.AVPlayer.status:Error: \(self.player.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Sin descripción"), error: \(self.player.error.debugDescription ?? "Sin error")")
        } else if #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status) == keyPath && newStatusAsNumber.intValue == AVPlayerItemStatus.failed.rawValue {
            // This get called after 20 seconds
            NSLog("observeValue.AVPlayer.currentItem.status:Error: \(self.player.currentItem?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Sin descripción"), error: \(self.player.currentItem?.error.debugDescription ?? "Sin error")")
        }
    }
}

// Never called
@objc func newErrorLogEntry(notification: Notification) {
    if let object = notification.object, let playerItem = object as? AVPlayerItem, let errorLog = playerItem.errorLog() {
        NSLog("newErrorLogEntry:Error: \(errorLog)")
    }
}

// Never called
@objc func failedToPlayToEndTime(notification: Notification) {
    let error = notification.userInfo!["AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeErrorKey"] as? NSError
    NSLog("failedToPlayToEndTime:Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Sin descripción"), error: \(error.debugDescription ?? "Sin Error")")
}
```

This is the error that I get immediately but I don't know how to capture it:

> Task .<1> finished with error -
> code: -1007

This is the error that I get after 20 seconds and a lot of retries:

> [] < SEGPUMP> IndexFileHandleLongDownloadTimer: no response for initial index file in 20 seconds
>
> 2018-08-22 20:36:13.213040-0300 observeValue.AVPlayer.currentItem.status:Error: too many HTTP
> redirects, error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007
> "too many HTTP redirects" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=too many
> HTTP redirects, NSUnderlyingError=0x604000057c10 {Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-1007 "(null)"}})

I am new to iOS development so any help is welcome. If you consider that there is a better approach, please, let me know. Thank you!

Comment: It's told you that there are too many HTTP redirects. Is the URL good in Web Browser like Chrome?

Comment: Thank you @YunCHEN. Yes, the URL is OK. It is by design that it sends a 302 when session is expired (I don't know why but it is not under my control). I need to know when AVPlayerItem fails because of 302. But I don't know how to capture it.

Comment: Use `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to test URL at the same time, and cancel the AVPlayer if the 302 status code returned.

Comment: Hi @YunCHEN! Yes, I was thinking about that, but I decided to ask here before doing something like that. The case that I'm not addressing with that approach is when session finishes while reproducing a video. So, I wanted to know if there is another way to test this. However, if I don't find other solution, I suppose I'll end up doing this. Thank you!